# ng-repeat: how do I properly reference $odd or $even by variable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I reference `$odd` or `$even` by variable in `ng-repeat`? 
I am trying to do this:

```
<ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$odd">these are odd{{item}}</div>
<ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$even">these are even {{item}}</div>
```

By doing this:

```
<div ng-repeat="side in sides">
  <div ng-include='template'></div>
</div>

//template
<ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="side">these are {{side}} {{item}}</div>

//in the controller
$scope.sides = ['$odd','$even']
```

`{{side}}` results in `$odd` and `$even` text on the document where expected, but all the `{{item}}` are coming through.

I've tried `ng-if="side"`, `ng-if=side`, `ng-if={{side}}`, `ng-if=" 'side' "`.
I'm sure this is just my rookie ignorance at play and its staring me right in the face.

Edit:::

Sorry I wasn't clear. Assigning $odd and $even was simple enough if I wanted to write out the whole layout longhand, which I relented and did for now. What I would like to do, however, is use ng-include to template the reused portions of the layout as much as possible. A very simplified version of my layout looks something like this:

What I would like to do is turn something like this:

```
<div class="outer-column1">
  <div class="innercolumnA">
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat"thumbnail in thumbnail" ng-if"$even"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="innercolumnB">
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat"thumbnail in thumbnail" ng-if"$odd"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-column2">
  <div class="innercolumnA">
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat"thumbnail in thumbnail" ng-if"$even"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="innercolumnB">
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat"thumbnail in thumbnail" ng-if"$odd"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

into something like this:

```
<div ng-include="outer-column" ng-repeat="outercolumn in outercolumns"></div>

//template outer-column
<div class="outer-column">
  <div ng-include="inner-column" ng-init="innercolumns = [$odd,$even] " ng-repeat="innercolumn in innercolumns"></div>
</div>

//template inner-column
<div class="innercolumn" ng>
   <div ng-include="'thumbnail'" ng-repeat"thumbnail in thumbnail" ng-if"innercolumn"></div>
</div>

//template thumbnail
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
```

The question is: how can I reference the $odd and $even variables for ng-if indirectly? for example, I tried an `ng-init="sides = [$odd,$even]" and passed that in the ng-repeat for the innercolumn template` and put `ng-if="side"` into the template, but no go.

I also thought about passing a function like ng-if="whichSide(side)" That would return $odd or $even, but it seems like the $odd and $even variables are not defined on the $scope object...

But that's the spirit of what I'm trying to understand regarding the $odd and $even variables and indirectly referencing them.... Hope that makes sense. The project is working just fine, it's just annoying to make changes to 10 lines of code whenever I make an update vs. 3 lines of templated layout. Thanks!

Comment: hey.... @dan chow, was my answer able to help you? Will you please respond with some findings?

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry for the delay:

Answer (score 5):

`$odd` and `$even` are available variables in an `ng-repeat`. It looks like you are instead trying to evaluate a string literal. Observe the following example and model your working copy from there...

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="o in items" ng-if="$odd" class="odd">index: {{ $index }} value: {{ o }}</div>
    <div ng-repeat="o in items" ng-if="$even" class="even">index: {{ $index }}  value: {{ o }}</div>
</div>
```

---

```
// -- for visual demo. ng-if will work the same
.odd  { background-color: dodgerblue; }
.even { background-color: tomato; }
```

---

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
})
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/o6ypzqzm/) - working demo

Also, I'm not entirely sure what your overall goal is, but in my example, I am applying classes to style `$even` and `$odd` for demonstration. AngularJS offers [ngClassOdd](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd) and [ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven) as an alternative for accomplishing this as well. Lastly, if you are evaluating both `$even` and `$odd` - all items will of course show.

---

Check out the [ngRepeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for available variables you will have to evaluate

> - `$index`  - iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
> - `$first`   - true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
> - `$middle`  - true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator.
> - `$last`   - true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.
> - `$even`    - true if the iterator position $index is even (otherwise false).
> - `$odd`     - true if the iterator position $index is odd (otherwise false).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my inquiry to better reflect my intention, sorry I wasn't clear. I had already marked up the layout using $odd and $even in the longhand markup, but was trying to collapse it into a templated layout that utilized the ng-include awesomeness and ran into trouble trying to dynamically assign $odd or $even to nested items.